# MVC with View Model - Create an object optionally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I use MVC with View Models (I create separate View Model for each View). 
I have 2 objects; Product and Category; Product can have a category. 
I have separate view models (productCreateVM, CategoryCreateVM)

I can create product or category;and user can choose one of current categories while creating a new product, no problem.

What I need to do is that ; users can choose one of current categories or create a new category than choose it, while creating a new product.

If I add CategoryCreateVM in ProductCreateVM, then CategoryCreateVM's mandatory fields need to be filled in, in order the model state to be valid.
 but if user already found a category for their product and didnt create a new one; I can not fill all the mandatory fields of CategoryCreateVM.

On the other hand; if user is creating a new category from product create view; then all the validations should be applied (category name lenght etc).

Any suggestions how to approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use more complex validations see if http://foolproof.codeplex.com/ will be sufficient.

It it should provide you with the conditional validation you need

Answer (score 0):

You should consider rendering the Create Category View as a partial view within the Create Product View.

Its visibility can be toggled by e.g. the selection of Create Category within a Category drop-down menu.

For example:

```
@Html.Partial("Category/Create")
```